# Deploying docker-compose containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to deploy an app that's built with docker-compose, but it feels like I'm going in completely the wrong direction.

1. I have everything working locally—`docker-compose up` brings up my app with the appropriate networks and hosts in place.
2. I want to be able to run the same configuration of containers and networks on a production machine, just using a different `.env` file.

My current workflow looks something like this:

```
docker save [web image] [db image] > containers.tar
zip deploy.zip containers.tar docker-compose.yml
rsync deploy.zip user@server

ssh user@server
unzip deploy.zip ./
docker load -i containers.tar

docker-compose up
```

At this point, I was hoping to be able to run `docker-compose up` again when they get there, but that tries to rebuild the containers as per the `docker-compose.yml` file.

I'm getting the distinct feeling that I'm missing something. Should I be shipping over my full application then building the images at the server instead? How would you start composed containers if you were storing/loading the images from a registry?

Comment: I don't see anything related to D?

Comment: @Bauss Good catch, just typo'd entering the docker tag.

Comment: I don't understand, you say that docker-compose tries to rebuild the containers from docker-compose.yml which doesn't make sense unless something calls `docker-compose up` with `--build`.
My only idea is to `docker images` in your prod box and check the image names and tags match the ones in docker-compose.yml.

Comment: @Stratos I think the problem was that the docker images no longer had a tag after `docker load` them from the tar files.

Comment: @DanPrince that was my suspicion, is it all fixed?

Comment: @Stratos I ended up scrapping the save/load & manual transport option and just switched to using a registry instead. I'll write up an answer this evening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the same docker-compose.yml file in development and production.

The app service didn't specify a repository name or tag, so when I ran `docker-compose up` on the server, it just tried to build the Dockerfile in my app's source code directory (which doesn't exist on the server).

I ended up solving the problem by adding an explicit image field to my local docker-compose.yml.

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: 'my-private-docker-registry:latest'
    build: ./app
```

Then created an alternative compose file for production:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: 'my-private-docker-registry:latest'
    # no build field!
```

After running `docker-compose build` locally, the web service image is built with the repository name `my-private-docker-registry` and the tag `latest`.

Then it's just a case of pushing the image up to the repository.

```
docker push 'my-private-docker-registry:latest'
```

And running `docker pull`, it's safe to stop and recreate the running containers, with the new images.