# starting a docker container with an image created using "docker-compose build"

Tags: docker

I am trying to start an Docker image that was created using `docker-compose build`.

When in the correct directory, `docker-compose build` works fine

When in the correct directory, `docker-compose up` works fine as well.

I have a `docker-compose.yml` that looks like the following:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    image: apostx-cc-backoffice-work
    command: python3 backendworkproj/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

The problem is that when I run:

`docker run -d  --name apostx-cc-backoffice-work apostx-cc-backoffice-work`

the **container does not start at all** - I get no messages or anything ..

`docker ps` does not show any containers started.

How can I start this?

TIA

## update for Sergiu

@Sergiu - here are the results of your suggestion ..

```
$ docker run -d --name test apostx-cc-backoffice-work
07f012c11047b34834c5dac840aefcb8164355b9a65d6beca43350f450d5b7fb
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

## Here is the info:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
07f012c11047        apostx-cc-backoffice-work   "/bin/bash"         11 minutes ago      Exited (0) 11 minutes ago                          test
dd42f4b957e7        apostx-cc-backoffice-work   "/bin/bash"         About an hour ago   Exited (0) About an hour ago                       apostx-cc-backoffice-work
```

I am wondering if this could be the key to resolving the issue:
[Deploying docker-compose containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871950/deploying-docker-compose-containers)

## Here is an update:

$ docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
07f012c11047        apostx-cc-backoffice-work   "/bin/bash"         36 minutes ago      Exited (0) 36 minutes ago                          test
dd42f4b957e7        apostx-cc-backoffice-work   "/bin/bash"         About an hour ago   Exited (0) About an hour ago                       apostx-cc-backoffice-work
1e3298e55da1        wmaker-locl-officework      "catalina.sh run"   5 months ago        Exited (143) 5 days ago
```

And this is what happens when I looked at the logs for the exited items:

```
$ docker logs 07f012c11047
<no output>
$ docker logs dd42f4b957e7
<no output>
```

## Update for BMitch

@BMitch - thanks for the response. This is one of the documents I am following: [Dockerizing the DJango Application](https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-django-application)

Is it possible to convert a Docker project created with:
    `docker-compose build`
so that it generates an image that can be ran using
    `docker run -d --name <label_name> <image_name>`

In the `docker-compose.yml` file, I specified the option of :
    `image: apostx-cc-backoffice-work` so that an image would be generated.

You were correct with regards to the CMD line I had in the Dockerfile.

```
It was :
    `CMD ["/bin/bash"]`
Now it is
    `CMD [ "python3", "/code/backendworkproj/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" ]`
```

**The `Dockerfile` is as follows (took some items out to make it shorter):**

```
FROM python:3.6.2
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/

[..snip ..]

# the code built/referenced when using the "docker-compose build" command
ADD . /code/

CMD [ "python3", "/code/backendworkproj/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

> In the `docker-compose.yml`, I used the option below so that an image
>   would be created:
>
> ```
>     image: apostx-cc-backoffice-work (pls see  `docker-compose.yml` above)
> ```

**Below are commands tha were ran**

```
# ls
appmaster.pth  backendworkproj  backendworkproj@tmp  docker-compose.yml  Dockerfile  requirements.txt

# ls backendworkproj
appmasterdata  backendworkapp   db.sqlite3   manage.py  static
authorization  backendworkproj  generalinfo  README.md  usethis.txt

# docker run -d --name apostx-cc-backoffice-work apostx-cc-backoffice-work
dbc73335779a89b4fb31e91268c99b0e3f2b2ecbabe7bf136f82e11acbe70ee5

# docker container logs dbc73335779a
python3: can't open file '/code/backendworkproj/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have tried it with changes in the Dockerfile and still get the "can't open file" error :

=> CMD [ "python3", "full-path-to-the-file/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" ]

=> CMD [ "python3", "backendworkproj/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" ]

=> CMD [ "python3", "manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" ]

I cant do anything like:

```
`sudo docker exec -i -t 7bb5d8bfd45a /bin/bash`
```

since the container does not stay up long enough to do any troubleshooting.

I wanted to create an image file for use on the Deployment machine in order to avoid having to copy the entire directory to the Deployment machine (which seems to be a requirement when using "docker-compose up")

Is this possible? If not, is there a way to do this with "docker-compose up" so that all of the code does not have to be copied to the deployment machine?

TIA

## Update for BMitch

Thanks again @BMitch

The command worked on a "stopped container" just as you said.

```
# docker run -it apostx-cc-backoffice-work /bin/bash

root@5d66b0b648e9:/code# ls
Dockerfile  appmaster.pth  backendworkproj  backendworkproj@tmp  docker-compose.yml  requirements.txt

root@5d66b0b648e9:/code/backendworkproj# ls
README.md      authorization   backendworkproj  generalinfo  static
appmasterdata  backendworkapp  db.sqlite3       manage.py    usethis.txt

root@5d66b0b648e9:/code/backendworkproj# pwd
/code/backendworkproj

root@5d66b0b648e9:/code/backendworkproj# ls -alrt
total 208
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  11676 Oct 29 17:27 usethis.txt
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Oct 29 17:27 static
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    813 Oct 29 17:27 manage.py
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Oct 29 17:27 generalinfo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 155648 Oct 29 17:27 db.sqlite3
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Oct 29 17:27 backendworkproj
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 Oct 29 17:27 backendworkapp
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 Oct 29 17:27 authorization
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Oct 29 17:27 appmasterdata
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      0 Oct 29 17:27 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Oct 29 17:27 .idea
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root   4096 Oct 29 17:27 .git
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root   4096 Oct 29 21:56 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root   4096 Oct 29 23:32 ..
```

In `Dockerfile`, I made the change to CMD:

> CMD [ "python3", "/code/backendworkproj/manage.py runserver
>   0.0.0.0:8000" ]

I made no changes to `docker-compose.yml` I then ran the following:

```
docker-compose build

docker rm -f apostx-cc-backoffice-work
```

And finally, I ran the OS commands below (but still got the error)

```
# docker run -it --name apostx-cc-backoffice-work apostx-cc-backoffice-work
python3: can't open file '/code/backendworkproj/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

# docker run -it apostx-cc-backoffice-work /bin/bash

root@c70ae7ea289e:/code# which runserver

root@c70ae7ea289e:/code# ls /code/backendworkproj/manage.py
/code/backendworkproj/manage.py

root@c70ae7ea289e:/code# which runserver

root@c70ae7ea289e:/code# python --version
Python 3.6.2
```

Comment: maybe it does't work because you are trying 2 pass 2 names when it takes just one?

Comment: I was doing "docker run -d --name <display_name> <image_name>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Casey,

So according to your new edit, I can see that your container runs and then once it finishes the process, it exits

If you would do a `docker ps -a` you should see your *run and exited* containers .

To test that what I am saying is true, I would recommend you changing the *command* to something like */bin/true* or */bin/bash* to see if the container keeps running

**EDIT**:

Also, I was looking for what you are trying to do and I found this which you might find useful:

https://howchoo.com/g/y2y1mtkznda/getting-started-with-docker-compose-and-django

https://blog.syncano.io/configuring-running-django-celery-docker-containers-pt-1/

**EDIT 2:**

To see what happen you could do `docker logs 07f012c11047` which will give you a better understanding of what the issue might have been

Comment: Thanks but I am past the tutorials suggested. My problem is exactly like this  one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871950/deploying-docker-compose-containers

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
docker run -d  --name apostx-cc-backoffice-work apostx-cc-backoffice-work
```

will launch a container from your image using the default command. From your `docker ps -a` output:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
07f012c11047        apostx-cc-backoffice-work   "/bin/bash"         11 minutes ago      Exited (0) 11 minutes ago                          test
```

that command is `/bin/bash`, which you are running without any input defined. By default, when bash runs without any input, it immediately exits. That's the same inside and outside of the container:

```
$ bash </dev/null
$
```

The comment "container does not start at all" is inaccurate. It does start, and it is immediately exiting. There are no logs in the container just like there is no output in the bash line above.

If you wanted to use the options defined in your docker-compose.yml, then instead of a `docker run` command, you should have done a `docker-compose up`.

---

From your changed question, the error:

```
python3: can't open file '/code/backendworkproj/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

is telling you that python is looking for a filename: `/code/backendworkproj/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` rather than `/code/backendworkproj/manage.py`. You need to separate the arguments on your command line when you use the json formatting. So replace:

```
CMD [ "python3", "/code/backendworkproj/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

with:

```
CMD ["python3", "/code/backendworkproj/manage.py"," runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Comment: thanks for the info. Can you see the update in the post? Is it actually possible to convert a project that was created with "docker-compose build" so that a created image can be executed with a "docker run" command? If not, is it possible for the "docker-compose up" functionality to be ran ~without~ having to copy all of the source code to a deployment machine? Again, thanks for the input!

Comment: If you need to test in an interactive shell inside your container, run your bash command and replace `-d` with `-it`.

Comment: thanks but the container is not running. I ran "docker run -it --name apostx-cc-backoffice-work apostx-cc-backoffice-work" and got the following as a result "backendworkproj/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: OK - I did that.  Still got error (I noted what I did in the post) - doing more research ..